# What colour format is used in command block commands?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

I just started using command blocks in Minecraft and I'm stuck. I'm trying to make a custom firework rocket colour with this command.

```
give @p minecraft:firework_rocket{
    Fireworks:{
        Flight:2,
        Explosions:[{
            Type:1,
            Flicker:0,
            Trail:1,
            Colors:[I;86219204], // What is this colour format?
            FadeColors:[I;16886219] // same here
        }]
    }
} 1
```

I have tried with HEX and RGB and it doesn't seem like it's any of those.
For reference `I;2651799` is cyan; `I;1973019` is black; and `I;15790320` is white.

I used [this](https://www.digminecraft.com/generators/give_fireworks_rocket.php) page to check these values by just ticking the boxes in the *Select the Explosion Colors* section, generating the command, and checking the value.

Thanks for your help,
Huky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried with HEX and RGB and it doesn't seem like it's any of those.

But it is! Colors specified through NBT use the hex format (`#RRGGBB`). However, Minecraft's NBT parser does not support hexadecimal numbers, only base 10. So this means you have to convert between base 10 and hex. For example, the color `#FF0000` in hex is `16711680` [in base 10](https://www.google.com/search?q=0xff0000%20in%20base%2010)!